# Why are random variables mapped from the sample space?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

I've seen this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/46386) but something is bothering me. The accepted answer hints to the fact that we have to define a random variable on the sample space rather than on the field of events.

*I'm struggling to see why is this the case*.

In their book [Probability, random variables, and stochastic processes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071226613) Papoulis and Pillai discuss, in section 2-2, the Probability space. They say that, and I quote, "In the applications of probability theory to physical problems, the identification of experimental outcomes is not always unique." For a die rolling experiment, for example, we can define the sample space $S$ to be $S_1=\{f_1, \dots,f_6\}$ ($f_i$ faces of die) or $S_2=\{\text{even},\text{odd}\}$ (for even and odd number faces).

For me, $S_2$ can be seen as a subset of $S_1$ representing events, i.e. $S_2$
can be seen as a field $\mathcal{F}$ of events constructed from $S_1$. Which is to say that if we consider our sample space as $S_2$ we can interpret a random variable $X$ as being mapped from this sample space $S_2$ or from the field $\mathcal{F}$ equivalently!

am I wrong? Please correct me if I am. Any thoughts on that are appreciated.

Comment: The elements of $S_2$ can be thought of as events on $S_1$, but the sigma algebra on $S_2$ is $\{ \{\}, S_2, \{even\}, \{odd\} \}$.

Comment: @JackM Okay. suppose $\mathcal{F}=\{\{\}, S_2, \{even\}, \{odd\}\}$ the $\sigma$-algebra on $S_1$. Can we consider this $\sigma$-algebra as a sample space on which we define a random variable $X$?

Comment: Sure. Any set can be made into a probability space by taking its power set for a sigma algebra. But that random variable $X$ may or may not have a meaningful interpretation.

Comment: Good. Now my question is, if we can interpret $\mathcal{F}$, which is $\sigma$-algebra on $S_1$ as a sample space, then we can define a random variable $X$ on this  $\sigma$-algebra (field). Then, why do we say that we can't define a random variable from the field of events (our $\sigma$-algebra). I think I'm missing something here!

Comment: @MedNeit Take a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$. If you want, you can go ahead and define a random variable $X$ on the space $(\mathcal F, \mathcal P(\mathcal F))$. But that probably won't be very useful. I'm essentially forgetting about the fact that $\mathcal F$ is a sigma algebra and just thinking of it as a set, and putting a brand new sigma algebra on it.

Comment: @JackM Why won't that be very useful?

Comment: What would the meaning of such a random variable be?

Comment: @JackM For elements $\{even\}$, and $\{odd\}$ of $\mathcal{F}$ we associate a value for the cases where the die shows even or odd values. But for $S_2=\{even, odd\}$ I think this case doesn't happen, to have even and odd values at the same time! Unless two dice are rolled! Also you cannot have the case $\{\}$; something has to happen, no? I think this is what kccu meant by his answer. So, you cannot define a random variable on a $\sigma$-algebra because it necessarily includes the subset containing all elements and the empty subset, for which we do not know how to define a random variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S_2$ is not a $\sigma$-field, though. Rather, $S_2$ is a partition of the sample space, and the random variable $X$ which is $1$ if the die roll is odd and $0$ if the die roll is even is a function $X:S \to \{0,1\}$ which is constant on the sets in the partition $S_2$. That is, $X(f_1)=X(f_3)=X(f_5)=1$ and $X(f_2)=X(f_4)=X(f_6)=0$.

If $S_2$ were a $\sigma$-field we would have to include $\emptyset$ and $\{f_1,\dots,f_6\}$. How would you define $X(\emptyset)$? $X(\{f_1,\dots,f_6\})$?

Comment: Why is $S_2$ not a $\sigma$-field? Is it because the intersection of even and odd is not in the field I defined? If so, can we not consider the empty set as part of our field to make it a $\sigma$-field and work with that?

Comment: Also how would you define $X(\emptyset)$ and $X(\{f_1, \dots, f_6\})$ of our sample space was $S_1 = \{f_1, \dots, f_6\}$?

Comment: @MedNait $S_2$ is not a $\sigma$-field because it is not closed under intersections and unions. If the sample space is $S_1$ then $X$ is defined on the elements of $S_1$, i.e., $X(f_1), \dots,X(f_6)$. I defined these in my answer.

Comment: It took me a while, but I think I got it. Thanks.